# unused argument date in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I am getting an odd error when I try to extract the year from a date object

here is a dput of my dates:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(15706, 15707, 15708, 15709, 
15710, 15711), class = "Date")), .Names = "date", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

when I pipe to `lubridate::year(date)` I get the following error.

```
Error in year(., date) : unused argument (date)
```

Comment: Not clear how you did that.  `dates %>% mutate(year = lubridate::year(date))`  or `dates %>% pull(date) %>% lubridate::year(.)`  where 'dates' is the dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `pipe` if you do that, it wouldn't work because of the order or evaluation

```
 dates %>%
     lubridate::year(date)
```

> Error in lubridate::year(., date) : unused argument (date)

---

Either we need to `pull` the column and then apply the function

```
dates %>%
   pull(date) %>%
   lubridate::year(.)
```

Or another way is to use the function within `{}`

```
dates %>% 
   {lubridate::year(.$date)}
#[1] 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013 2013
```

Or use the standard way of creating column by using `mutate`

```
dates %>% 
    mutate(year = lubridate::year(date))
```

Answer (score 2):

Having named your object `data`, I'm assuming this is what you did:

```
data %>%
    year(date)
```

That also didn't work for me. You can try this:

```
year(data$date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use `magrittr` operator `%$%`:

```
library(magrittr)
dates %$%
  year(date)
```